# Typesafe activator: Java JDK not installed or can't be found

Tags: java

I am trying to run the typesafe activator on Windows7 (32bit).I have JDK 1.8  installed. It keeps saying I don't have a valid JDK installation:

A Java JDK is not installed or can't be found.

Please go to
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
and download a valid Java JDK and install before running Activator.

If you think this message is in error, please check
your environment variables to see if "java.exe" and "javac.exe" are
available via JAVA_HOME or PATH.

Comment: First check if you have set the JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables. Also, it may be the case that typesafe activator doesn't support Java-8. Try using with Java 7.

Comment: thanks. And when I open the activator.bat something like "the syntax of the command is incorrect ." is appearing in cmd. What should I do?

Comment: Edit you question and post the contents of `activator.bat` here.

Comment: play eclipsify doesn't work?
C:\Users\DJ\asd>play eclipsify 
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\DJ\asd\project
[info] Set current project to BeamstreamPlay (in build file:/C:/Users/DJ/asd/)
[error] Not a valid command: eclipsify (similar: eclipse) 
[error] Not a valid project ID: eclipsify 
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: eclipsify 
[error] eclipsify 
[error]          ^

Comment: @Dj-U-Know I got the same thing. Turned out, there's a "java.exe" in \windows\system32\ conflicting with the JDK version. In my case I fixed this by going into the Windows environment variables dialog and moving `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` in the PATH to the beginning of the path string so that it precedes `%systemroot%\system32;`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Windows 7 64b. The problem solved by changing the installed directory from  "C:\Program Program..." to a directory without space like "c:\java".

So the solution is: Installing Java to a path without spaces.

I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Activator Directory (not the Java Directory) where it's path does not contain spaces! (ie C:\Program Files\ ... is NOT valid)

Also place the Java PATH before all other paths in your Environment Variables.